# How to modify chartjs tooltip so i can add customized strings in tooltips

Tags: javascript, chart.js

How do i edit chartjs tooltip to add customized strings in tooltips

[image]

For Example: I want to change the Tooltip like "January: 28 Files" or just "28 Files"

Comment: there is a tooltip configuration HTML that is available as an option when you define the Global Configuration Options: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#getting-started-global-chart-configuration

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides didn't notice that. Now i can change the template tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %> Files" Thanks :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Redefine default global tooltip template as follows:

```
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTemplate =
  "<%if (label){%><%=label%>: <%}%><%= value %>";
```

Here is another example:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(data, {
        tooltipTemplate: "<%= value %> Files"
});
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work for V2 of chart.js. If you are in trouble, please take a look to my answer or on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720530/chart-js-v2-add-prefix-or-suffix-to-tooltip-label)

Answer (score 6):

The great previous answers do not work with chartjs 3. This example is from [the official  documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html):

```js
const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        plugins: {
            tooltip: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(context) {
                        var label = context.dataset.label || '';

                        if (label) {
                            label += ': ';
                        }
                        if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
                            label += new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { style: 'currency', currency: 'USD' }).format(context.parsed.y);
                        }
                        return label;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Drawing from other responses I've found that helped me, apparently the label properties can be set to functions, For example, to format currency:

```js
var overrides = {
  // show lables as currency
  scaleLabel: toCurrency,

  // String - Template string for single tooltips
  tooltipTemplate: toCurrency,

  // String - Template string for multiple tooltips
  multiTooltipTemplate: toCurrency
}

function toCurrency(label) {
    return '$' + label.value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```