# Chart.js V2: Add prefix or suffix to tooltip label

Tags: chart.js

In Chart.js V1.0, I would add `tooltipTemplate: "<%if (label){%><%=label %>: <%}%><%= '€' + value %>"` to add a euro symbol as prefix to the tooltip label. However, this no longer works in V2. Does anybody know the new way to do accomplish this? I can't seem to find it.

Many thanks!

Comment: Here is an example an Doughnut chart with a percentage tooltip **(Chart.js 4.4.0)**  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77230228/6155490)

Answer (score 126, accepted):

In the V2.0 the tooltipTemplate option is deprecated. Instead you can use callbacks to modify the displayed tooltips. There is a sample for the usage of callbacks [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/samples/tooltips/callbacks.html) and you can find the possible callbacks in the [documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) under *Chart.defaults.global.tooltips*

In your case I would do the following:

```
window.myLine = new Chart(chart, {
    type: 'line',
    data: lineChartData,
    options: {
            tooltips: {
                enabled: true,
                mode: 'single',
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
                        return tooltipItems.yLabel + ' €';
                    }
                }
            },
     }       
  });
```

Don't forget to set the HTML meta tag:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: If you have problems displaying the tooltips after that, please look into this issue and how to fix it: https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/issues/1891

Comment: for v3,  I resolved the issue by
`options: { plugins: { tooltip: { callbacks: { label: callbackFunction } } } }`

Comment: v3 official example here https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/configuration/tooltip.html

Answer (score 60):

In addition to iecs' answer, if you want to return the **exact default text** and add some more (like a € sign in your case), use following syntax :

```
var ctx = $(chartCanvas);
window.chartObject = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartData,
    options: {            
        tooltips: {
            callbacks: {
                label: function(tooltipItems, data) {
                    return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label +': ' + tooltipItems.yLabel + ' €';
                }
            }

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This is what I've been searching for half the day, thank you!! All other suggestions kept replacing the default text and label.

Comment: V3 has an example of how to do this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.5.0/configuration/tooltip.html

Answer (score 21):

See if it helps:

```
        var config = {
            options: {
                tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        title: function (tooltipItem, data) { return data.labels[tooltipItem[0].index]; },
                        label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                            var amount = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                            var total = eval(data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data.join("+"));
                            return amount + ' / ' + total + ' ( ' + parseFloat(amount * 100 / total).toFixed(2) + '% )';
                        },
                        //footer: function(tooltipItem, data) { return 'Total: 100 planos.'; }
                    }
                },
            }
        };
```

Comment: Using ChartJS 2.7.1 and the above helped me to display the Label, Value and a Symbol after many hours of searching.

Answer (score 13):

This set "label + value + €"

```
options: {
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                return data.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ': ' + data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index] + '€';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. The accepted answer doesn't work for me, maybe it did work at the time...

Comment: This answer works for Donut, Pie and other type of graphs like this. This should be the accepted answer I guess.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a **stacked bar** chart (and I assume a stacked line chart) and you want to format all the data points included in a single bar with a currency symbol, you can do something like this:

```
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'label',
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                return '$' + tooltipItems.yLabel;
            }
        }
    },
```

Note the value of `mode`.

If you want to have finer control of the tool tip, for example include the labels as they appear the chart's legend, you can do something like this:

```
    tooltips: {
        mode: 'single',  // this is the Chart.js default, no need to set
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                var i, label = [], l = data.datasets.length;
                for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                    label[i] = data.datasets[i].label + ' : ' + '$' + data.datasets[i].data[tooltipItems.index];
                }
                return label;
            }
        }
    },
```

Comment: This worked for me with a slight modification on the first code block. There's an extra 's in ``tooltipItem`` in this line ``return '$' + tooltipItems.yLabel``. This results in no tool tips visible.

Answer (score 7):

Just updating @Luc Lérot's answer. 
I had the same problem and his code helped me out but not fixed it, I had to modify it to work for me.
Using Chart.js version 2.6.0

```
var ctx = $(chartCanvas);
window.chartObject = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: chartData,
    options: {            
        tooltips: {
               callbacks: {
                   label: function (tooltipItems, data) {
                       return data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label + ': ' + data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index] + ' €';
                   }
              }

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

As we continue our way along the release chain, the answer once again changes in Chart.js v3.X with the updated options API.

An example of adding temperature units is as follows:

```js
const options = {
    plugins: {
        tooltip: {
            callbacks: {
                label: (item) =>
                    `${item.dataset.label}: ${item.formattedValue} °C`,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To generalize code, let's use `unitPrefix` and `unitSuffix` for the datasets, for example:

```
datasets: [
    {
        label: 'Loss Rate',
        data: [],
        unitSuffix: "%",
    },
    {
        label: 'Price',
        data: [],
        unitPrefix: "$",
    },
```

Then we could have this code:

```
options: {
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
            label: function (tooltipItem, data) {
                let dataset = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex];
                let blocks = [];
                if (dataset.label) {
                    blocks.push(${dataset.label} + ':');
                }
                if (dataset.unitPrefix) {
                    blocks.push(dataset.unitPrefix);
                }
                blocks.push(dataset.data[tooltipItem.index])
                if (dataset.unitSuffix) {
                    blocks.push(dataset.unitSuffix);
                }
                return blocks.join(' ');
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js version 3.9.1

```
const options: ChartOptions = {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: ({ label, formattedValue }) => `${label}:${formattedValue}g`
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See tooltip section:

```
const options = {
      interaction: {
        mode: "nearest",
        intersect: false,
      },
      scales: {
        y: {
          grid: {
            display: false,
          },
          position: "right",
        },
        x: {
          ticks: {
            maxRotation: 0,
            minRotation: 0,
          },
        },
      },
      plugins: {
        legend: {
          display: false,
        },
        tooltip: {
          callbacks: {
            title: function (context) {
              return data[context[0].dataIndex].date //in title you have to call context[0] in order to get current item
            },
            label: function (context) {
              return context.raw //raw will give you the label value
            },

            intersect: false,
            backgroundColor: "#51d198",
          },
        },
      },
    }
```