# Chart.js 2.0: How to change title of tooltip

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, chart.js

Forgive me for my sometimes poor English. Dutch is my native language.

I've created a Chart.js linechart which shows me my energy usage reported by my main power smart meter. I got it almost working like the way I want, but there is one thing I can't manage to get it to work in a way I want because I don't understand a little thing.

With some help of the user "iecs" at the topic ["Chart.js V2: Add prefix or suffix to tooltip label"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855201/6660135) I was able to change the label at the tooltip. It now shows nicely my desired prefix and suffix:

```
tooltips: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'single',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)',
    titleFontSize: 14,
    titleFontStyle: 'bold',
    titleFontColor: "#FFF",
    bodyFontSize: 12,
    bodyFontStyle: 'normal',
    bodyFontColor: "#FFF",
    footerFontSize: 12,
    footerFontStyle: 'normal',
    footerFontColor: "#FFF",
    cornerRadius: 5,
    callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItems, data) { // Solution found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855201/6660135
            //Return value for label
            return 'Usage: ' + tooltipItems.yLabel*1000 + ' watt';
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to add exactly the same code to modify the title I got `undefined` at the place where a date and time should be displayed:

```
tooltips: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'single',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.9)',
    titleFontSize: 14,
    titleFontStyle: 'bold',
    titleFontColor: "#FFF",
    bodyFontSize: 12,
    bodyFontStyle: 'normal',
    bodyFontColor: "#FFF",
    footerFontSize: 12,
    footerFontStyle: 'normal',
    footerFontColor: "#FFF",
    cornerRadius: 5,
    callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
            //Return value for title
            return 'Date: ' + tooltipItems.xLabel + ' GMT+2';
        },
        label: function(tooltipItems, data) { // Solution found on https://stackoverflow.com/a/34855201/6660135
            //Return value for label
            return 'Usage: ' + tooltipItems.yLabel*1000 + ' watt';
    }
}
```

With the answer of user "Lukman" at the topic ["Print content of JavaScript object? [duplicate]"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625271/6660135) I discovered that I can display the content of the "tooltipItems object":

```
alert(tooltipItems.toSource())
```

This displayed an interesting difference regarding the "tooltipItems" object between the "title" and the "label".

The "tooltipItems" object at the "label" display this as content:

```
({xLabel:"2016-08-07 23:41:57", yLabel:0.261, index:70, datasetIndex:0})
```

While the "tooltipItems" object at the "title" displays this as content:

```
[{xLabel:"2016-08-07 23:41:57", yLabel:0.261, index:70, datasetIndex:0}]
```

The beginning characters and ending characters are different.
The one of "label" can be read with `tooltipItems.yLabel` but the one of "title" can't be read with `tooltipItems.xLabel` because it shows me "undefined". The whole title will now be `Date: undefined GMT+2` insteas of `Date: 2016-08-07 23:41:57 GMT+2`

What did I mis? Can someone explain me the differences between the 2 outputs of the object contents of "tooltipItems" and how to read the "xLabel" and "yLabel" indexes?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem too, but was resolved with this.

```
return 'Date: ' + tooltipItems[0].xLabel + ' GMT+2';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This indeed solved my problem! :-)

Appreantly these are differences:
`({xLabel:"2016-08-07 23:41:57", yLabel:0.261, index:70, datasetIndex:0})` is a object. I already recognized that. And `[{xLabel:"2016-08-07 23:41:57", yLabel:0.261, index:70, datasetIndex:0}]` appearantly respresents an array. The place where I did have to look for the data I needed was array index 0 (zero).

Comment: This is because some fields, like `title`, are passed an array of `toolTipItem` objects; others, like `label`, are passed a single object. You can see which here, in the "Arguments" column: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks

Answer (score 2):

I needed to manipulate title tooltip, and solved it. Reviewing the source chart.js for v 3.7.1, find callback for title, line 11759:

```
callbacks: {
    title(tooltipItems) {
    if(tooltipItems.length > 0) {
        const item = tooltipItems[0];
        const labels = item.chart.data.labels;
        const labelCount = labels ? labels.length : 0;
        if (this && this.options && this.options.mode === 'dataset') {
            return item.dataset.label || '';
        } else if (item.label) {
            return item.label;
        } else if (labelCount > 0 && item.dataIndex < labelCount) {
            return labels[item.dataIndex];
        }
    }
    return '';
    }
}
```

In my tooltip case, work with "item.label" return. Virtually copy and paste the code and works fine, in my case needed some text cut, over the return title.

Sorry by the english, helped by Google Translate.