# chart.js substitute tooltipItems

Tags: javascript, tooltip, chart.js

I'm trying to create a bar chart using chart.js (2.0) that return a different string for each tooltipItems instead of the tooltipItem itself: I've seen [how to add a prefixed text after the tooltipItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720530/chart-js-v2-add-prefix-or-suffix-to-tooltip-label) but I haven't found any solution for my problem.
I've tryied something like this:

```
tooltips: {

                    mode: 'single',
                     callbacks: {
                            label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
                                    for (i=0; i<tipData.length; i++) {
                                          return tipData[i];
                                    }
// other possible version
//                                  for(var p in tipData){
//                                      return tipData[p];
//                                  }
                        }
                       }
                      },
```

but it's not working.
Thank you in advance for any help and best regards.

Comment: Is the 'tipData' the array that holds the strings that you want to display as tooltips?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to specify it, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change your code the following way:

```
tooltips: {
    mode: 'single',
    callbacks: {
         label: function(tooltipItems, data) { 
                return tipData[tooltipItems.index]
         }  
    }
}
```